# ProgressBar does not animated in GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, view, progress-bar, google-maps-android-api-2

I use the same component ProgressBar in Activity layout and in InfoWindowAdapter

My ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/stoMapInfo_progressBar"
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:indeterminate="true"

     />
```

In Activity it animates normal, but in InfoWindow it shows static

```
   map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            StoItem item = StoMarkersCollection.getInstance().containsMarker(marker);

            if(item!=null){

                return item.getInfoContent(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sto_map_info, null),marker);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        }
    });
```

I know, that InfoWindow has any restrictions (onClick works only for all window), probably nonanimated ProgressBar - one from restriction.
Can I fix it?